# Android — Google Drive API get public folder files with public key?

Tags: android, google-api, google-drive-api

I've tried many solutions, but I still can not connect to the public folder.

1. Please give me a link to a real working example to access a public folder by using a Public key.
2. It is not clear, the disc can be connected only through `OAuth`, or using Public key?

In the console, `"Deive API"` is enabled.

The project has created.

Private key is generated.

After a connection is triggered `"GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener"`

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.apps.drive.APP_ID"
        android:value="id=AIzaSyAXbNLlQ_M"/>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
</application>
```

GoogleUtil

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.Drive;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveApi;
import com.google.android.gms.drive.DriveFolder;

public class GoogleDiskUtil implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "CLASS_GOOGLE_DISK_UTIL";

    public static final String EXISTING_FOLDER_ID = "0B_SGgMtbKW-efktGZUNjWVI3cFU1anFzUTFFS2F3Y1pfOVZlYk9VUnpQcDNRd2pEOWp2TDA";

    private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private Activity activity;


    public GoogleDiskUtil(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        registerDrive();
        Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(mGoogleApiClient, EXISTING_FOLDER_ID)
                .setResultCallback(getFolderCallback);
    }

    private void registerDrive() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(activity)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
//                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER) // required for App Folder sample
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult> getFolderCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.DriveIdResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.DriveIdResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Cannot find DriveId. Are you authorized to view this file?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            DriveFolder folder = Drive.DriveApi.getFolder(mGoogleApiClient, result.getDriveId());
            folder.listChildren(mGoogleApiClient)
                    .setResultCallback(metadataResult);
        }
    };

    final private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataResult = new
            ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult result) {
                    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Problem while retrieving files", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Successfully listed files.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            };


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
        if (!connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(connectionResult.getErrorCode(), activity, 0).show();
            return;
        }
        try {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "trying to resolve the Connection failed error...");
            connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(activity, 1);

        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Google Drive for Android only supports authorization of the current user, meaning files within your drive. I think this does **not** include files shared with you, let alone public folders. You'll have to use the [Java Client Library](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java) to access public folders.